# Redhat installation not getting network adapter detected on Hyper-v, how to fix this?

Tags: redhat, hyper-v

I have installed Redhat version 6 and 7 both.

Both have the same problem.

No IP address.

WHen I checked, no network interface also.

ip a s

only shows loopback adapter.

Any help?

I am able to see the network adapter and set static ip to ubuntu on the same hyper-v server

Comment: I had the same problem on Gen 2 HyperV (UEFI) VM, Oracle Linux 7. Less than minimal installation, after installing I had removed dhcp client also (I would use static IP only). Had to reinstall dhcp client and also run dracut to fix.

Comment: can you share the steps you followed

Answer (score 0):

The steps:
I reinstalled these packages:
`yum install dhclient dhcp-common dracut-network`
(I had also removed `network-manager` which is included on minimal installation, but it wasn't needed to be reinstalled in order to restore functionality)

Ran `dracut -f` after reinstallation, rebooted and the adapter was available once again. Yet it delayed a bit to appear, so I changed some systemd services to start after network.